# AVPlayer set initial playback time iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avplayer

Added `KVO` for `AVPlayer` when to play video as `queuePlayer` is `AVPlayer`

```
[self.queuePlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:NULL];
```

`observer` `method`:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
    if (self.queuePlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {

        NSInteger step = (NSInteger)(startTimeForVideo/0.04);
        [self.queuePlayer.currentItem stepByCount:step];

        //CMTime seekTime = CMTimeMake(startTimeForVideo*timeScale,timeScale);
        //if (CMTIME_IS_VALID(seekTime)) 
        //  [self.queuePlayer seekToTime:seekTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimePositiveInfinity toleranceAfter:kCMTimePositiveInfinity];
        //else
        //  NSLog(@"In valid time");

        [self.queuePlayer play];
    } else if (self.queuePlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
        /* An error was encountered */
    }
}
```

Here `startTimeForVideo` intial `playBack time` for `video`

`seekToTime` not working neither `stepByCount`

**EDIT** : `Values` of `object` used in `methods` are `correct` and even though `no luck`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes in `KVO` method as `queuePlayer` is `AVPlayer`:

```
if (self.queuePlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) 
{
  //firstly make cmtime as here startTimeForVideo is Float64 value in seconds
  //get video's time scale as CMTime has it. 
  int32_t timeScale = self.queuePlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale
  CMTime seektime=CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(startTimeForVideo, timeScale);
  //use this cmtime for seekToTime. 
  [self.queuePlayer seekToTime:seektime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
}
............
```

**EDIT** : Here `kCMTimeZero` in both `tolerance field` for `exact location` in `seekToTime: toleranceBefore: toleranceAfter:` method